# Python:: how to insert %d into variable when defining a function

Tags: python-2.7

How can you insert %d into a variable inside a def code so that the variables change according to the parameters given to the function?

```
def ratio(iterA, iterB):
   a=0.0
   b=0.0
   for i in range(20000):
       if (data2.iter%d[i] % iterA) < 0.2:
           if (data2.iter%d[i] % iterB) < 0.2:
               a += 1
           else:
               b += 1
   return a/b
```

This function is currently giving off errors of sorts. How can get to have data2.iter~ input variable change according the parameters I give which are iterA and iterB? For example if I give iterA as 1 and iterB as 15, then the resulting code would hopefully be computed as

```
a1=0.0
b1=0.0
for i in range(20000):
    if data2.iter1[i] < 0.2:
        if data2.iter15[i] < 0.2:
            a1 += 1
    else:
        b1 += 1
print(a1/b1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want `data2` to be a two-dimensional array.  Then you can use:

```
if data2[iterA][i] < 0.2:
     if data2[iterB][i] < 0.2:
         #...
```

---

Ok, ok.   If you really need to do this, `getattr(obj, name)` is what you are looking for.   Ie)

```
if getattr(data2, 'iter%d' % iterA)[i] < 0.2:
    #....
```

But don’t do this lookup 20000 times!  Move it before the loop:

```
listA = getattr(data2, 'iter%d' % iterA)
#...
for i in range(20000):
    if listA[i] < 0.2:
        #...
```